# Changing image source using JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, src

I am trying to change src of an image based on day. But the src is not updating.
What is the problem?

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
image = new Array(7);
image[0] = 'img/about-img1.jpg';
image[1] = 'img/about-img2.jpg';
image[2] = 'img/about-img3.jpg';
image[3] = 'img/about-img4.jpg';
image[4] = 'img/about-img1.jpg';
image[5] = 'img/about-img4.jpg';
image[6] = 'img/about-img5.jpg';
var currentdate = new Date();
var imagenumber = currentdate.getDay();
document.getElementById("special").src=image[imagenumber];
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img  id="special" src="">
</body>
```

Comment: What is `ImageArray`? Perhaps you meant `Array`.

Comment: Are you using MasterPages to build the page?  If so, the name of the element may have "MainContent_" attached to the front of the ID preventing you from finding it with getelementbyID...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access the DOM before it is even loaded. Put the script tag below the `<img>` at the end of the `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
<img  id="special" src="">

<script type="text/javascript">
image = new ImageArray(7);
image[0] = 'img/about-img1.jpg';
image[1] = 'img/about-img2.jpg';
image[2] = 'img/about-img3.jpg';
image[3] = 'img/about-img4.jpg';
image[4] = 'img/about-img1.jpg';
image[5] = 'img/about-img4.jpg';
image[6] = 'img/about-img5.jpg';
var currentdate = new Date();
var imagenumber = currentdate.getDay();
document.getElementById("special").src=image[imagenumber];
</script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, look into using a `window.onload` event to ensure your script is executed *after* the DOM is loaded (similar to jQuery's `$(function() { });` but using plain JavaScript).
See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: Yeah .. That was the problem .Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to place the javaScript code in the body *after* the `<img>` tag. Using it in the head executes it, before the image DOM element exists and so `getElementById()` doesn't find anything.

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img  id="special" src="">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var image = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5],
        currentdate = new Date();
    document.getElementById("special").src = 'img/about-img' + image[currentdate.getDay()] + '.jpg';
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah .. That was the problem .Thanks +1